# How to use template strings with graphql-codegen?

Tags: typescript, graphql-codegen

I have this GraphQL query in a TypeScript file:

```
const someVar = 'getUser'

export const SOME_QUERY = gql`
  query ${someVar} {
    user {
        name
    }
  }
`
```

but when I run `graphql-codegen` to generate the types, I get this message in the terminal:

```
[client-preset] the following anonymous operation is skipped: 
  query  {
    user {
      name
    }
  }
```

Looks like the template string is not being picked up.